# "Local variable referenced before assignment " appears when putting code into function

Tags: python, factoring

My code works fine until I try putting it into a function. Once I define the function, indent the code, and call the function, I get the error message:

> "Local variable 'print' referenced before assignment.

Why is that popping up when all I'm changing is putting it into a function? I never assign a variable 'print.' Please help!
I blocked out the token to access the server I am trying to reach for security.

```
    def printSet():
        for user in range (0,len(parsed_json['members'])-1):
            userDict=parsed_json['members'][user]#Catches errors resulting from users not having all settings configured
            try:
                print("id: "+userDict["id"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No ID found")
            try:
                print("team id: "+userDict["team_id"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No team ID found")
            try:
                print("name: "+userDict["name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No name found")
            try:
                print("real name: "+userDict["real_name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No real name found")
            userProf=userDict['profile']
            try:
                print("title: "+userProf["title"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No title found")
            try:
                print("real name: "+userProf["real_name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No real name found")
            try:
                print("real name normalized: "+userProf["real_name_normalized"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No real name normalized found")
            try:
                print("display name: "+userProf["display_name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No display name found")
            try:
                print("display name normalized: "+userProf["display_name_normalized"])
            except KeyError:
                 print("No display name normalized found")
            try:
                print("email: "+userProf["email"])
            except KeyError:
                print:("No email found")
            try:
                print("first name: "+userProf["first_name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No first name found")
            try:
                print("last name: "+userProf["last_name"])
            except KeyError:
                print("No last name found")
    #To easily show when one member ends and another begins
            print("----------------------------------")
    printSet()
```

Comment: You'll have to show us what the code looks like when it produces the error. Showing us the working code and asking about the non-working code doesn't give us a lot to work with.

Comment: Sorry! Pasted the wrong thing. Fixed now.

Comment: Well `parsed_json` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere

Comment: Where is `userProf` defined?

Comment: @SuperStew Sorry, now I explain in the question. I define it at the top of my code and I'm sure that's not the issue. I only pasted that function

Comment: @mypetlion here:  except KeyError:
            print("No real name found")
        userProf=userDict['profile']
        try:
            print("title: "+userProf["title"])

Comment: The error almost certainly means that somewhere in the function you’re accidentally assigning to `print`, maybe with a `print =` or `print, something = something` or maybe a `for print in something` or `something something as print:`. Since only you can see your actual code if you don’t post a [mcve], you will have to find that somewhere yourself. But once you do, it should be obvious how to fix the mistake. If not, post an example that includes that mistake and no other errors that prevent people from even getting that far, and we can help.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the help!  I updated my question to include the full code. I don't think I assign anything to `print` anywhere, though.

Comment: The code as posted does not raise the exception you’re asking about. It does raise an `IndentationError` before you can even call the function, which makes it pretty clear this is still not your actual code, much less a useful [mcve].

Comment: @abarnert Hmm, it should work. Try again?

Comment: After your last edit, an hour after my comment, yes, it now compiles and runs and, if I go through the trouble of creating a valid `parsed_json` object because you didn't bother to give us one, it reproduces the error. But it shouldn't take hours of back-and-forth comments and me trying to read your code to figure out what the input is supposed to look like to make your question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I never assign a variable 'print.'

Yes you do:

```
print:("No email found")
```

This is an [annotated assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements), which annotates `print` with type `"No email found"`, but assigns no value.

An annotated assignment always creates a local variable, even if you aren't assigning a value. From the docs:

> If a name is annotated in a function scope, then this name is local for that scope.

In case you're wondering, empty annotated assignments are useful for cases like this:

```
n: int
if spam:
    n = spam**2
else:
    n = -1
```

This is the only way you could tell a static type checker like Mypy to verify that `n` ends up holding an `int` no matter which `if` branch you take.

Answer (score -1):

"I assign parsed_json elsewhere in my code"

Well that's the issue. You have to pass the variable to the code, or declare it global, but best to avoid this. You could make the simple change like so.

```
def printSet(parsed_json):
    for user in range (0,len(parsed_json['members'])-1):
       userDict=parsed_json['members'][user]
    #####do a bunch of stuff or whatever

printSet(parsed_json)
```

Note that you would need to do this for each variable you use in your function

Something else to simplify you code and help debug would be getting rid of all the try-excepts

```
keylist=["id", "real_name", ..... "last_name"] #not required, but helpful if you want to print "not found" type messages
for k in keylist:
    if k in userDict.keys():
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, userDict[k]))
    else:
        print('No {} found'.format(k))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I made that change, but I'm still getting the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: This couldn’t cause the error the OP reports, with `print` being an unassigned local variable.

Comment: @NoaKligfeld which line exactly does the error occur on

Comment: @NoaKligfeld i made an edit to my answer that might help

Comment: @SuperStew here is the error message: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noak\OneDrive - California Association of Realtors\My Files\Desktop\StackExchange", line 61, in <module>
    printSet()
  File "C:\Users\noak\OneDrive - California Association of Realtors\My Files\Desktop\StackExchange", line 11, in printSet
    print("id: "+userDict["id"])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Ok so after `print("No ID found")` the `try` statement does not have the exact same amount of indentation as the lines above. This could be an issue. You would need to make sure they all have the exact same indentation, or use the method i posted above

Comment: @SuperStew hmm, it should be at the same level.

Comment: @nklick it appears to be off by a few spaces, it looks close on first glance, but when i copied into a text editor, i could see the difference